# I'm trying to get data from a text file delimited by tabs. but i'm unable to get the result

Tags: c, pointers

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main() {

    FILE *fp;
    char buff[1024];
    char q1[6];
    char q2[6];
    char * pch;
    int i;

    fp = fopen("QFile.txt", "r");
    fgets(buff, 255, (FILE*)fp);
    pch = strtok (buff,"\t");
    int count=0;
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        q1[0]=("%s",*pch);
        pch = strtok (NULL, "\t");
    }

    fgets(buff, 255, (FILE*)fp);
    pch = strtok (buff,"\t");
    count=0;
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        q2[0]=("%s",*pch);
        pch = strtok (NULL, "\t");
    }
    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
        printf ("%s\n",q1[i]);

    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
        printf ("%s\n",q2[i]);

    fclose(fp);
}
```

This is my QFile.txt looks like :

```
1   20 % of 2 is equal to   1)1 2)0.4   3)0.5   2
2   If Logx (1 / 8) = - 3 / 2, then x is equal to   1)-4    2)4 3)1/4   2
```

when i'm compiling, it shows some warnings:

```
test3.c:4:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 main() {
 ^

test3.c: In function ‘main’:
test3.c:32:10: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
  printf ("%s\n",q1[i]);
          ^

test3.c:35:10: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
  printf ("%s\n",q2[i]);
          ^
```

I can't figure out how to correct this . I want to get two mcq questions to two arrays.How do i fix this?

Comment: What's the `q2[0]=("%s",*pch);`?

Comment: `for(i=0;i<6;i++)
printf ("%s\n",q1[i]);` does not make sense as only `q1[0]` is set.

Answer (score 1):

```
test3.c:4:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
main() {
^
```

*main()* defaults to returning an *int*. Write

```
int main() {
```

and return an int, `0` to tell the caller everything was ok

```
   return 0; // final line of main
}

test3.c: In function ‘main’:
test3.c:32:10: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
  printf ("%s\n",q1[i]);
      ^

test3.c:35:10: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
  printf ("%s\n",q2[i]);
          ^
```

`q1` and `q2` are char arrays, so `qx[y]` gives the (y+1)th element of those arrays, i.e. a char.

If you actually want to print the character at position `i`, use `%c` (characters are casted to `int`, hence the warning `int`)

```
  printf ("%c\n",q1[i]);
  printf ("%c\n",q2[i]);
```